# What Libre Office PPAs are available?

Tags: libreoffice, ppa, downgrade

I think that I have to downgrade from LibreOffice 4.1.0.4 because of the bug in the time display.

My previous version was 3.5.4. Is the 3.5.4 PPA still available?

Do any of the versions between 3.5.4 and 4.1.0.4 handle Base report writing better?

Comment: Which specific PPA were you you using? Please add the details to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to downgrade your version  of LO then remove the current PPA of LO from the software sources . after doing that open your terminal and paste these following line one by one in your terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-3-5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

That will installs libreoffice-3-5 in your Ubuntu.

One more point , this PPA is available for only 12.04 LTS.

If you want to install  libreoffice-3-6 , because its applicable upto Ubuntu 12.10. you can do it as

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-3-6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

hope that helps.

Comment: if the OP is using 12.04 - there is no point in using a PPA to install 3.5 - just purge the 4.1 PPA and this will reinstall v3.5.

Comment: Following your instructions and suggestions (thanks!) I'm trying to remove 4.1 and install 3.6. I'm on my 3rd try as 4.1 is very persistent.

I've hunted down and removed every LO file I can find. I am wondering if the "sudo apt-get update" command might be at fault, since it is going to the Ubuntu repositories for the update files. Won't the 4.1 files be the files selected?

Comment: @fossfreedom i agree with you my master.

Comment: @KatrinaAdams if you purge PPA of 4.1 then you no need worry.